# creating a file with touch using a variable

Tags: bash, variable, touch

I have this variable :

`toto=123456`

why does `touch "$toto.hihi.log"` works and creates a file called *123456.hihi.log*

but `touch "$totohihi.log"` doesn’t do anything ?

Comment: you could also do `touch $toto\hihi.log` or `touch $toto'hihi.log'` or `touch "$toto"hihi.log`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need

```
touch "${toto}hihi.log"
```

The problem is that the shell cannot know without the braces how many characters are part of the variable name. Thus it treats all legal characters as a part of the name. In this case that is everything before the `.`; i.e. the shell uses the non-existing variable `$totohihi`.

In general it helps to use the shell option `-x` to see what is going on:

```
set -x
touch "$totohihi.log"
    + touch .log
```

Comment: Hi Hauke, I want to know how can I set and use the variable for one line? E.g. `n=2 touch "ab${n}.txt"` does not get `ab2.txt`, but get `ab.txt`.

Comment: @Rick `n=2 touch` runs `touch` with the environment variable `n`. That is not what you want. You want the shell to expand `${n}` thus `n` must be defined in the shell context: `n=2 ; touch "ab${n}.txt"`

Comment: Ok, I see, I need a comma, thank you @Hauke :).

Answer (score 3):

It does, it expands `$totohihi` to the empty string, and then runs `touch ".log"` (assuming the variable wasn't set elsewhere). Try to see what `ls -l .log` says.

As mentioned by the other answers, you need to wrap the variable name in braces if the following characters can be part of a variable name, so `touch "${toto}hihi.log"`. Note that the underscore is also valid in variable names along with letters and numbers, so `"${toto}_hihi.log"` would also need braces.

Answer (score 1):

`$totohihi.log`  means variable with name `totohihi`

for it to work, use

`${toto}hihi.log`

[This stackoverflow answer has good explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8748880/3143562)

Answer (score -1):

Shell knows that `$toto` is a variable with value `123456`.
Hence, wherever it finds `$toto` it replaces it with `123456`.
So in case of `$toto.hihi.log`, shell replaces `$toto` with `123456` as `.` is like a concatenation operator and  creates a file as expected.

However, in case of `$totohihi.log`, shell does not find any variable named `$totohihi` and hence replaces it with empty string resulting into creation of file `.log`. You may find it with `ls -a` or `ls .log` as files starting with `.` are hidden files and cannot be seen with simple `ls` command.

In case you need to create file with name `123456hihi.log`, you will have to put `$toto` in curly braces as `${toto}hihi.log` as mentioned by others in previous answers.

Comment: The dot is just a dot, not a concatenation operator. There is no such operator in the standard shell syntax.

Comment: Oh! I meant it's like a concatenation operator and not actually an operator.